# how does this sentence need a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, independent-clauses

I do not like biology nor do I like chemistry.

"do I like chemistry," being the independent clause doesn't make sense to me on its own.

If my grammar/punctuation in this question is incorrect, please tell me. I'm trying to improve it for a job I have answering emails.

Comment: Does it *need* a comma?  I would think that It can take a comma or not, depending on your particular writing style.

Comment: *Neither/nor* is a far better construction if you have editing privileges. __I like neither biology nor chemistry.__ No commas are used with *neither/nor* constructions unless the sentence is markedly bulky. __I like neither the memorization and laboratory work associated with biology, nor the number crunching and homework load so common to chemistry.__

Answer (score 4):

Whenever two independent clauses are separated by a conjunction, it is customary to precede that conjunction with a comma:

1. I do not like biology, **nor** do I like chemistry.
2. I do not like biology, **and** I also do not like chemistry.
3. I do not like biology, **but** I really do like chemistry.

That said, this general guideline is often rescinded for short clauses:

4. He showed up **and** I left immediately.
5. He showed up **but** I’d already gone.
6. He went to the store **or** he stayed home; I don’t know which.

Comment: I'm sure this is at least a partial repeat, but I doubt the answer given elsewhere is as pithy, so I'll not bother looking.

Answer (score 1):

"I do not like biology nor do I like chemistry" is completely understandable but that doesn't make it correct. It does need a comma, between "biology" and "nor".

The reason "do I like chemistry" doesn't make sense to you is that it's not an independent clause; it's not any clause, on its own. Others will be better able to explain whether "a clause" would really be simply "I like chemistry" or the whole 
"nor do I like chemistry" but nevertheless to look at "do I like chemistry" as a clause is to misunderstand the whole thing.

Answer (score -2):

I do not like biology, nor do I like chemistry.

"Nor do I like chemistry" is a modifying clause to the original sentence, therefore can be separated by use of a comma

Comment: What do you think it modifies? (By the way, I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: It modifies the original clause by expanding the range of 'things I do not like'

Comment: Modification describes, which is to say it restricts, not expands. *do I like chemistry* is an independent clause, one of two conjoined by *nor* to form the sentence.